# Handling missing images without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, http-status-code-404

I would like to create a clean solution for handling missing image on the client

using  `<img src="image.gif" onerror="handleErrors()">`

so far the handleErrors looks like this:

```
function handleErrors() {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
    return true;
}
```

But I feel this is not scalable enough and the no image is also not accessible for screen readers.

What could be a more scalable and accessible solution for this problem?

Comment: img{width:100%;height:100%} doesn't help? Or set a min height and width by % maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the alt text attribute for your images.

> They are more accessible for screen readers.
>
> Also you can create a module which on error hides the images and
>   replaces them with their alt text

Here is a module I wrote for handling such issues:

```
function missingImagesHandler() {
    var self = this;
    // get all images on the page
    self.pageImages = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    self.ImageErrorHandler = function (event) {
        // hide them
        event.target.style.display = 'none';
        // replace them with alt text
        self.replaceAltTextWithImage(event.target);
    }
    self.replaceAltTextWithImage = function (imageElement) {
        var altText = imageElement.getAttribute("alt");
        if (altText) {
            var missingLabel = document.createElement("P");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(altText);
            missingLabel.appendChild(textnode)
            imageElement.parentNode.insertBefore(missingLabel, imageElement);
        } else {
            console.error(imageElement, "is missing alt text");
        }                    
    }
    self.attachErrorHandler = function () {
        self.pageImages.forEach(function (img) {
            img.addEventListener("error", self.ImageErrorHandler);
        });
    }
    self.init = function () {
        // NodeList doesn't have forEach by default
        NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
        self.attachErrorHandler();
    }
    return {
        init: self.init
    }
}
var ImgHandler = new missingImagesHandler();
ImgHandler.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<img id="myImg" src="image.gif">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("myImg").onerror = handleErrors();

function handleErrors() {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png";
    return true;
}
```

Give an ID to image and use this for call your function:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").onerror = handleErrors();
```

Giving an ID is more suitable way.